# Will size of people increase when Kali yuga will change to Satya yuga?

Tags: yuga, kali-yuga

It is said that in Satya yuga people were a lot larger than today in Kali yuga. And it is said in Bhagavata purana and in several other places that when Kalki avatara will destroy all sinners at the end of Kali yuga, then all saints which will be still alive at that time will feel a great relief and thus a next Satya yuga will begin. But the people in Kali yuga are really small compared to Satyua yuga standards! Will these survivors suddenly increase in height?

Comment: I don't think the survivors would magically increase in height, I think their descendants will increase in height.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Well, I guess that, too, but it would be great to get some *shastra*'s to read about it. :)

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan In Satya Yuga, people were about 30 feet in height. Ashwatthama is also around 14 feet tall. As the Kali Yuga progresses, people will become smaller and smaller i.e at least around 1-2 feet. When Satya Yuga will start, their descendants won't suddenly go from 1-2 feet to above 30 feet. This is because Satya Yuga won't start at all! Remember Sri Yukteswar's theory. Slowly slowly people will increase in height and it will all make sense. Just another reason why Sri Yukteswar was absolutely right.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria I think the transition in height could be achieved fairly easily in the Sandhya and Sadhyansa transition periods between Yugas.  In any case, do you know of any scriptures that mention ascending and descending Yugas?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan I don't know about any Hindu scriptures but Jainism has somewhat same concept.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria Well, as far as I know all the Hindu scriptures that discuss the order of the Yugas don't mention the ascending and descending thing, so I trust Hindu scripture over Yukteswar's theory.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan As Sri Yukteswar said, the wrong information came through certain Sanskrit scholars like Kulluka Bhatta.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria who is Sri Yukteswar's *diksha-guru*? What *sampradaya* he belongs to?

Comment: @hijarian Yukteswar was a disciple of Lahiri Mahasaya, who is believed to be a disciple of a 2000-year old sage called Mahavtar Babaji.  These figures would all be part of the Advaita Sampradaya.  In fact, followers of Babaji even believe that Babaji was the one who gave diksha to Adi Shankaracharya.

Comment: @hijarian Lahiri Mahasaya was a famous Kriya Yogi. Kriya Yoga was revived by Mahavatar Babaji and Paramahamsa Yogananda once said "Kriya Yoga is the aeroplane method to reach God".